# Is it possible to open ios/android app without custom url scheme?

Tags: android, ios, web, deep-linking

Usually applications are opened via `custom://` registered url scheme with fallback to market / appstore.

Application i want to open does not have registered its custom url scheme both in Android and IOS.

Currently i have only one working solution for IOS - smart banners, but it is supported only in Safari:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=APPID">
```

Perhaps there is a way for Android and IOS to open app without custom scheme?

Comment: Smart banner (if you count it as a way...) is the only way on iOS if there is no custom url scheme.

Comment: @deadbeef seems so.. perhaps it is possible in Android?

Comment: Don't know about Android sorry.

Comment: So for Android/Chrome check 'Native App Install Banner': https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/increasing-engagement-with-app-install-banners-in-chrome-for-android?hl=en